# Let a Windows program (in Wine) capture stdout of a Linux program that it runs

Tags: windows, wine, output

I have a Windows program running under Wine.  That Windows program lets me set up "tools" to run external programs and then it will capture their standard output/error and show it to me within the Windows program's interface.

I want to be able to run a native Linux program as such a tool.  I am able to get my Windows program to run a Linux program, but it doesn't get access to the output.  Instead, the Linux program's output is shown in the console window from which I ran the Windows program.

My specific program is EditPad Pro, a text editor, but I would like if possible a solution that works for any Windows program that runs external programs.  (Many text editors have such a feature, for instance, to be able to compiler/run the source code being edited.)

As an example, I tried to run `/usr/bin/python3 --version` as an external tool, to test things. I open an ordinary linux terminal and do `wine myprogram.exe`.  Within Myprogram, I set up `/usr/bin/python3 --version` as an external tool.  (I have also tried using `start /unix` ahead of this but that didn't work either.)  When I run the tool, the Python version information is displayed in the linux terminal where I typed `wine myprogram.exe`.  Myprogram sees no output from Python.  But I want that output to be going to "Myprogram", which is the one running it, not to the linux terminal that launched Myprogram.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you exactly run `/usr/bin/python3` from your program?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: I specify the command line in the GUI of my program.  I don't know exactly how it's running it, although if you have ideas of how I can find out more about that that could be helpful.  I assume it is using some kind of system call to run my specified command (python3) as if it were being typed on the Windows command line.  I note that I get the same behavior if I try to run python3 from within a wineconsole, so I'm guessing something similar is going on with my program.

Comment: I thought that, since you were trying to capture `stdout`, you had access to the code. Who would consume `stdout` then?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: It is as I said: I specify a command line within "Myprogram" and say "run this command line as an external tool".  Myprogram runs whatever I tell it to, and Myprogram captures the stdout and shows it to me in the interface of Myprogram.  It is like a typical IDE/Editor feature where the editor allows you to run external tools (such as compilers) and see their output/errors within the editor.

Comment: Can you tell us the name of this MS program? Maybe someone has solved the exact problem.

Comment: Put amendments to the question in the question, so that they are all in one place. Thank you.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I've edited the question to mention the program, but I'd really like a solution that gives an arbitrary Windows program full access to all standard streams of arbitrary Windows and/or Linux programs, in the same way that a Windows process on Windows can access such streams.

Answer (score -1):

From what you say, I see no evidence that the MS program is capturing the stdout of the external tool: If the stdout is appearing in the terminal that launched the MS program ("Instead, the Linux program's output is shown in the console window from which I ran the Windows program."), then this indicates that the external program is inheriting stdout from its caller.

You need to find a way in your MS program to get it to read the data. Look to see what options it has:

- Does it have an option to read stdout of the external tool.
- Does it have a way to read a file, and to string command together.

Comment: It does have an option to read stdout of the external tool, and that's what I'm using.  The external program is not inheriting stdout because the Windows program has several options for what to do with the output (ignore it, put it in a new file in the editor, etc.) and those options work in Windows, so it's clear the Windows program is able to access the output of the external tool.  I think the problem is that *Wine* is inheriting stdout (or messing it up somehow) so that the Windows program does not have access to a real stdout stream for the external tool.

Comment: Also, if I do `wine cmd` to get a windows command prompt in a terminal, and then do `/bin/echo hello`at that windows prompt, the output shows up after the following windows prompt, indicating that windows is not waiting for the output of `echo` before going back to its own prompt.